# Fatal Error Mage.php on line 328 - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

When restoring magento using Xampp on mac i get This Fatal Error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP
/xamppfiles/htdocs/bengar17/app/Mage.php on line 328
```

I already changed the Permissions of all folders.

The code from the Mage.php is :

```
public static function getBaseDir($type = 'base')
    {
        return self::getConfig()->getOptions()->getDir($type);
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this might be a permission error in magento root folder run following commands in mac terminal

```
cd <path to your installation>
chmod -R 777 app/etc
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 media
```

find the complete guide [here](http://www.cs-blog.de/2012/04/17/install-magento-on-mac-with-xampp/)

Comment: It's weird!.. i've changed those permissions already! now i changed them again and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: guess you have done something wrong last time anyway, glad to help you buddy :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but it didn't wor for me (setting the 777 for those directories).

Comment: I actually didn't have directories /var and /media, so I created them and put 777 on them, and now it works, the fatal error doesn't show any more!